# Decoherence among entangled photons according MWI?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, decoherence

In MWI, say we have two photons that are entangled. They are described by the same wave function according to basic QM. Now according to MWI, what would happen if we measured photon 1 and make its position states decohere? Would photon 2 also decohere into separate position states or would it not decohere until it becomes detected?

This may be a duplicate but please, don't close this. I really need straight forward answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of  interpretation (but in those in which there is a collapse, or a split like in MWI), when you make a measurement on the first particle, the wave function collapses to an eigenstate (of the measured observable) of the first particle   instantaneously. For two particles this means that the wavefunction will be separable, because you can express the wave function as the product of the collapsed state of the first particle times the state of the other particle, regardless of if it is or is not being affected by the collapse.

Comment: So the second particle doesn't decohere in a position state if the first particle is?

Comment: Decoherence only means that the entire  state has to be written as a product of individual states, instead of being a non-separable function.  Thus, the second particle state can still be a mix of pure position  states for th second particle.

Comment: So in an entangled pair, if photon 1 decoheres, photon 2 can actually still create an interference?

Comment: yes.  But just in case wait for more answers, I might be missing something

Comment: That seems to be the most consistent answer that I have been researching, so you are probably right